# What buffering type do streams in C use?

Tags: c, file, pointers, file-io

Recently I started to learn I/O in C and came across the idea of 'streams' and 'buffering'. To my understanding, a stream is a purposeful abstraction of an interface used for input and output on a device. Normally an opaque type is known as `FILE` is used to create 'streams', this type is typedef'd to a struct that contains data about the input/output channels of a specific device, enabling low-level functions in the OS to deal with input/output in an easier manner.

Furthermore 'buffering' i learned was a way that streams use to function in a more efficient manner, streams use a segment of memory known as a 'buffer' which is very fast to write too and extract data from as opposed to storing data straight in memory. Buffers are used when input is taken through a stream, it is then stored in a buffer, and then when the input process is done, it is extracted from the buffer and written to the file or standard output medium at hand.

This is all well and good but I have one question... Buffering can be changed and the programmer is able to change buffering types at any time, the types are:

- No buffering
- Line buffering
- Full buffering

My question is, what is the default buffering that streams in C use?

You can assume what I mean by "streams" is the standard streams (`stdin`,`stdout`,`stderr`) and creating a stream with `FILE` type. What buffering do they all use?

Comment: Basically, text streams are line buffered, binary streams are not buffered (or fully buffered) ... with many **but**s and **if**s. `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are, usually, text streams (though `sdterr` is usually not buffered).

Comment: A buffer is in memory.  The point of the buffer is that it is faster to read from memory than to make multiple system calls.  In other words, if you ask for 1 character from a file, the system will read 8192 (or some other size) and store them in a buffer.  When you ask for the next character, it can be retrieved from the buffer without doing any IO.

Comment: @pmg, Re "*Basically, text streams are line buffered,*", Normally, stdout if only line buffered if connected to a terminal. It's block buffered the rest of the time. So why would other text handles be line buffered? That makes no  sense. (I have no idea what the standards say.)

Comment: Read [C11 7.21.3](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.3) paragraphs 3) and 7).

Comment: And to clarify this part: *"the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device"* -  "interactive device" is implementation-defined, so you can not necessarily assume a particular device behaves a certain way.

Comment: @pmg: indeed. But "interactive device" is not the same thing as a "text stream". Putting a `b` in the mode argument of `fopen` has no impact whatever on buffering.